# Integral w.r.t. a cumulative density function

Tags: probability, cumulative-distribution-function, integral

I was reading a paper and couldn't understand the following transition. Could someone tell me where the term of $p^k (\frac{1}{2} − c′)$ comes from in the following transition?

### Def: Cumulative function of interest

$$
F(x) =
\begin{cases}
    0 & \text{for } x < -c' \\
    p^k & \text{for } x \in [-c', 0) \\
    (p + (1 - p) x)^k & \text{for } x \in [0, 1] \\
    1, & \text{for } x > 1
\end{cases}
$$

### Integral of interest

$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x d F(x) = p^k (\frac{1}{2} - c') + \int^{1}_{0} x d F(x) = \cdots
$$

### My attempts

First, I expanded the integral based on the sections as follows;
$$
\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x d F(x) = \int^{-c'}_{- \infty} x dF(x) + \int^{0}_{-c'} x dF(x) + \int^{1}_{0} x dF(x) + \int^{\infty}_{1} x dF(x)
$$
Then, i was not sure how to compute each term... could someone tell me how to compute the integral over a CDF?

### Reference

- Appendix B of [this paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1512.07679.pdf)
- https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4605847/integral-over-a-cumulative-density-function

Comment: Perhaps graphing an instance of this family of functions would clarify the calculations.  Due to the four-part definition of $F,$ this result reflects four separate calculations: which one(s) are you wondering about?

Comment: @whuber thank you for your comment! Yeah, out of 4 sections, I'm wondering where $p^k (1/2−c′)$ comes from.

Comment: @whuber I think i was not clear about what to ask in the above post. Sorry!

Comment: Do you know what the notation $dF(x)$ indicates?  It's the derivative of the function $F$ with respect to $x$, handwaving over some details that aren't important here.  The first and last integrals should be clear... what is the derivative of a constant?  Then think carefully about what is happening with the transition between the first and second integral - follow @whuber's recommendation and plot the function - and that should help you with the second one.  Then on to the third one!

Comment: @jbowman thank you for your detailed suggestion! As you mentioned, 1st and 4th terms become 0 as the derivative of a constant in the CDF. Then, 2nd term will be $\int^{0}_{-c'} x p^k dx = [ \frac{1}{2} x^2 p^k ]^{0}_{-c'} = 0 - \frac{1}{2} c'^{2}p^k$....?

Comment: oh, so is it like $\int^{0}_{-c'} x dF(x) = \int^{0}_{-c'} x p^k$? then we get $[x p^k]^{0}_{-c'} = 0 - c' p^k$. But still I don't know where 1/2 comes from then....

Comment: Well you still have the third term, the integral over $[0,1]$.

Comment: @jbowman Sorry, I'm a bit confused. In the transition of interest ( $\int^{\infty}_{-\infty} x d F(x) = p^k(\frac{1}{2} - c') + \int^{1}_{0} x dF(x)$ ), the third term ( $ \int^{1}_{0} x dF(x)$ ) that we are discussing now still remains, right? So, I thought the second term ( $ \int^{0}_{-c'} x dF(x)$ ) will somehow generate the quantity of $p^k (1/2 - c')$

Comment: Oh, no, it just generates the $-p^kc'$ term.  Basically, there's a jump in $F$ at $-c$, which means there's a discrete mass at that point, that has probability $p^k$.  So its contribution to the expected value is just $-c * p^k$.

Comment: @jbowman Got it! And I'm really sorry for asking a lot.. but then do you know where $1/2 p^k$ comes from?? Summarising our discussion, wow we know that in the transition in `My Attempts` of the question, the first and final terms become 0 and the second term generates $-c' p^k$ and the third term remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

Let us express the CDF in terms of the Heaviside function $H(\cdot )$, this function is defined by,
$$ H(a) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} 1 & \text{ if } & a\geq 0 \\ 0 & \text{ if } & a < 0 \end{array}\right. $$
Note, $H$ itself is a CDF, in some sense it is the "simplest" CDF. Now, we will do something extremely *controversial*, we claim that the derivative of the Heaviside function is the delta function, i.e., $H' = \delta$. Where $\delta(\cdot)$ is defined as follows,
$$ \delta(a) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ccc} \infty & \text{ if } & a = 0 \\ 0 & \text{ if } & a\not = 0 \end{array}\right.$$
This is the delta "function", it has the additional property that, $\smallint_I (g\cdot \delta) = g(0)$ provided that $I$ is an interval that contains the singularity $0$ and $g$ is a continuous function at $0$. For instance, $\smallint_{(1,2)} (g\cdot \delta) = 0$ but $\smallint_{(-1,2)} (g\cdot \delta) = g(0)$. You can intuitively think of $\delta$ as a PDF, which integrates to $H$. Of course, no such function exists in the classical sense with such properties, but let us not be worried about that yet.

Now the function that you wish to integrate can be described by,
$$ F(x) =  p^k \bigg( H(x+c') - H(x) \bigg) + (p+(1-p)x)^k\bigg( H(x) - H(x-1) \bigg) + H(x-1)$$
Therefore, the "*derivative*" is equal to,
$$ F'(x) = \delta(x-1) + p^k \bigg( \delta(x+c') - \delta(x) \bigg) + k(1-p)(p+(1-p)x)^{k-1}\bigg( H(x) - H(x-1) \bigg) + (p+(1-p)x)^k\bigg( \delta(x) - \delta(x-1) \bigg)$$
Therefore, the calculation you are looking for is equal to,
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}} x ~ d F(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}} x F'(x) $$
Now substitute the above "*derivative*" and use the delta properties.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! In the last equation, isn't there $dx$ at the end of the integral of LHS??

Comment: No, it's a different kind of derivative than the Riemann integral we all learned in Calc I, and the notation is different.  In most practical cases, writing loosely, it'll be easily translatable into the usual integral, as you have done in your comments answering parts 1, 2, and 4 of the original post, but it fixes up some problems with the Riemann integral from a mathematical point of view, enabling a lot of really elegant proofs etc.

Comment: @Rowing0914 Yes, if you want to, you can write $x F'(x) ~ dx$ at the very end, but here the $dx$ is purely symbolic and serves no purpose any more. But if it makes it easier for you to understand the calculation then it just means you treat the integral of $x F'(x)$ as a usual integration problem with delta functions in there.